# Having troubles with arrays, getting illegal start of expression

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Hello So I'm currently in the progress of making a sorting program but I tried to create this method to display the things in the array and it keys giving me this. Im actually clueless on why this is giving me this error and tips/help would be appreciated

```
public static void DisplayData(double payrate[], String names[])
    {
         for (int l=0; l<=payrate.length; l++) 
         {

           locationsum = 0;

           locationsum+=payrate[l];
           }

           for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
           {
              System.out.print(names[i]);

           System.out.printf("%6d\n", locationsum);

           } 

    }


project3.java:69: error: illegal start of expression
    public static void DisplayData(double payrate, String names)
    ^
project3.java:69: error: illegal start of expression
    public static void DisplayData(double payrate, String names)
           ^
project3.java:69: error: ';' expected
    public static void DisplayData(double payrate, String names)
                 ^
project3.java:69: error: '.class' expected
    public static void DisplayData(double payrate, String names)
                                          ^
project3.java:69: error: ';' expected
    public static void DisplayData(double payrate, String names)
                                                 ^
project3.java:69: error: ';' expected
    public static void DisplayData(double payrate, String names)
                                                               ^
6 errors
```

Comment: You are having issue not with this code but having issue with before this method line.

Comment: You need to declare your method in a class. With a `project3.java` source, your method should be in `class project3 { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Typo in your posted code. You don't close `SortData`. Add a `}` before `public static void DisplayData` (you have two loops).

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to close `}` `SortData()` implementation. Before `DisplayData()` method just add `}`.

```
public static void SortData(double payrate[])
    {
        -----
    }//--> Missing closing here
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Verify your proper nesting of open`({)` and close `(})`. you have missed any of these two somewhere above this `Function`

```
public static void DisplayData(double payrate[], String names[])
```

Thank you